# What are these four seal script characters?

Tags: translation, seal

I noticed this mark on the bottom of a teapot. I'm having trouble identifying the four characters which I believe to be seal script. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The four characters are 章燕城制.
章燕城 is a quite famous teapot artist in China. You can get more information on this page https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%AB%A0%E7%87%95%E5%9F%8E/5490618?fr=aladdin